# How to define F# generic function argument in a generic function?

Tags: generics, f#

```
let getLogicalWithDoubleLevelElement<'E when 'E :> DoubleLevelElement>
    (logicalModifier : InletPosition * OutletPosition -> Logical)
    (logical : Logical) =
```

I need `logicalModifier` to be generic function with type the same type argument as `getLogicalWithDoubleLevelElement`.

How to define that?

Comment: re use `'E`? should be fine

Comment: Basically @John answered your question. I'm not sure whether there's some bigger misunderstanding as you function name may not reflect  function's signature. Do you want getLogicalWithDoubleLevelElement to take a Logical as one of its arguments or do you want it to return Logical or both?

Comment: It takes modifier function, than Logical, than returns modified Logical

Comment: @JohnPalmer could you provide an excerpt of code?

Comment: I assume the relevant signature is `logicalModifier : 'E -> Logical` or something similar - you aren't particularly clear on what you want

Comment: I want to pass generic argument `'E'` from `getLogicalWithDoubleLevelElement` function into its argument `logicalModifier` like this `logicalModifier<'E>`

Comment: But I can't figure out if it is possible to define a signature of a generic function in an argument of another generic function.

Comment: Does such syntax exist?

Comment: I think you need to write a clearer example - use some simpler variable names and write the whole function out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass an explicitly polymorphic function as an argument, then the only way to do that in F# is to use a new type with a generic method:

```
type LogicalModifier =
    abstract MakeLogical<'E when 'E :> DoubleLevelElement> : InletPosition * OutletPosition -> Logical

let getLogicalWithDoubleLevelElement<'E when 'E :> DoubleLevelElement>
    (logicalModifier : LogicalModifier)
    (logical : Logical) = ... logicalModifier.MakeLogical<'E> ...
```